# How to make one key stroke emit 3 unicode character in a custom keyboard layout in Linux mint?

Tags: linux, keyboard, linux-mint, keyboard-layout, unicode

I have created a custom keyboard layout for my regional language by editing different files. It works fine except for one problem. One of the characters needs 3 unicode characters in combination I.e. I want all the 3 characters to be emitted in single key stroke. Please help me to do so.

The characters are as follows

`ক + ্ + ষ --> ক্ষ`

`U0995 + U09CD + U09B7 --> ক্ষ`

This combination needs to be emitted from the third character of the key `key <AB04>`, shown below.

I added language file to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols` and entry to the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev.xml` file

extract from the file I added:

```
// shift, z to /
      // key <LFSH> { [ Shift_L ] };
               key <AB01> { [ U09A2,    U09A7,  U09B7,  voidsymbol ] };
               key <AB02> { [ U09A3,    U09A8,  U09B8,  voidsymbol  ] };
               key <AB03> { [ U09AA,    U09AF,  U09B9,  voidsymbol  ] };
               key <AB04> { [ U09AB,    U09F0,  voidsymbol, voidsymbol ] };
               key <AB05> { [ U09AC,    U09B2,  U09DC,  voidsymbol ] };
               key <AB06> { [ U09AD,    U09F1,  U09DD,  voidsymbol ] };
               key <AB07> { [ U09AE,    U09B6,  U09DF,  voidsymbol ] };
```

Needs to add the letter ক্ষ to the 3 rd position of 6th key in the shift L line from left.

[image: Needs to add the letter ক্ষ to the 3 rd position of 6th key in the shift L line from left.]

I am using Linux mint 21.3.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43073/ ? xkb has no support for 'combined' unicode glyphs (or at least it didn't 10 years ago). You can load it through an xmodmap config though

Comment: Yes it does explain partially still it's not quite clear how to do it. I am not able to follow it. and is there a better way?

Comment: You might look at the equivalent of AutoHotkeys for Linux, e.g., https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?style=19&t=106640 and https://alternativeto.net/software/autohotkey/?platform=linux

Comment: I haven't messed with it myself, but it may help to read through the explanation on `keysym` here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/X_keyboard_extension and the basics of `xmodmap`: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/xmodmap . You basically just set `keysym XF86LaunchA = U0995 U09CD U09B7` with modmap, then point to `XF86LaunchA` in your xkb config

Comment: I heve tried to follow this. But there is no positive result.

Comment: `xmodmap -e "keysym u = U0995 U09CD"` even I tried this. But in terminal it only prints one unicode at a time. prints the second on shift plus the key. 
`xmodmap -e "keysym a = e E"` will print only e or E not both.